# Mnesia DB elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, database, elasticsearch, erlang, logstash

I using ejabberd server for chat communication. I'd like be able dynamicly search my archive messages. Now I'm using elasticsearch and logstash, but it working only on mysql db. It's my logstash config

```
input {
        jdbc {
                jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ejabberd"
                jdbc_user => "ejabber"
                jdbc_password => "password"
                jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
                jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                statement => "SELECT * FROM ejabberd.archive"
             }
     }
output {
#       stdout { codec => json_lines }
        elasticsearch {
                index => "muc_room"
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
}
}
```

I need use mnesia DB, its default base for ejabber. How can connect mnesia DB with logstash, or it is possible use another way to include search engione to mnesia DB. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would send the data directly to elasticsearch from ejabberd. That way, you don't need to have two separate things that need to be updated if you change storage engines. There's [an Erlang package](https://hex.pm/packages/erlastic_search) to talk to Elasticsearch. The documentation on it isn't great, but it's a pretty simple interface anyway.